# How to bring down your namenode?

Tags: hadoop

#### How to bring down your Namenode in Hadoop 1.2.1 on CentOs and swap your namenode with a Datanode instance, also I have to make sure no data is lost during the process.

I am using Hadoop 1.2.1 with master, slave 1 and slave 2 nodes.

I am looking for the Unix commands or the changes I need to make in the configuration files.

Please ask for any particular details if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a back up of namenode metadata and kill namenode. Install namenode packages on other node of interest and put the  backup copy of  metadata in namenode data dir. Now start namenode this should pick up your old metadata. Remember to change namenode details in all config files.

Comment: How to kill the namenode?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep java` returns running java processes. you can use `kill -9 <pid>` to kill the namenode process.